# jQuery unexpected token due to margin-left

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am editing the css values of some elements via jQuery, when I attempted to change the margin-left value of an element, resulting in an "Unexpected token" error due to the "-" in margin-left. Is there a means of changing the margins via jquery without resulting in this error?

Here's an excerpt from my code:

**JS**:

```
$(".settingslist").click(function() {
    $(".containcontacts,.containtodolist").css({
        display: "none"
    });
    $(".gChange, .aChange, .yChange, .fChange,.speedChange, .bgChange, .simple, .gClick, .aClick, .yClick, .fClick,.speedSave, #Btn, .gSave, .aSave, .ySave, .fSave ,.bgChange, .fSave,.speedClick,.speedtext,#ImageUrl,.settingstxt,.containweather,#ddbtn").css({
        display: "block"
    });
    $(".gChange, .aChange, .yChange, .fChange,.speedChange, .bgChange, .simple").css({
        margin-left:"60px"
    });
});
```

For reference, the full program can be found here (I didn't create a snippet, because it is not an isolated part of the code):
https://codepen.io/Refath/pen/rdZwxE

Comment: margin-left needs to be quoted.

Comment: or changed to `marginLeft:`

Comment: Thanks; And I'm assuming this works for any such CSS property?

Comment: Yes. This is basic Javascript object literal syntax, has nothing to do with CSS.

Comment: You have to quote the property name if it contains any special characters.

Comment: `-` is the subtraction operator, it's like you wrote `margin - left: "60px"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, add double quotation marks on margin-left or use `marginLeft` instead.

Here is [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/css/)'s explanation:

> ...jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting of
>   multiple-word properties. For example, jQuery understands and returns
>   the correct value for both `.css({ "background-color": "#ffe",
>   "border-left": "5px solid #ccc" })`and `.css({backgroundColor:
>   "#ffe", borderLeft: "5px solid #ccc" })`. Notice that with the DOM
>   notation, quotation marks around the property names are optional, but
>   with CSS notation they're required due to the hyphen in the name.